# Alpine js sibling transition

Tags: laravel, transition, laravel-blade, alpine.js

What I am trying to achieve here is to animate sidebars.

Let's say there are two divs side by side (siblings), the left div can be toggled and the right main div is shown at all times. Now when I apply transitions (slide in and out) to left div while toggling works perfectly but the main div that sits right to the sidebar jumps while toggling the sidebar.

How do I transition the main div along with the sidebar?
I have gone through the docs and found "x-if" but that can only be used within template tag. And when I use it within the template tag all the elements within are not detected by javascript anymore.

By javascript I mean Algolia instantsearch.js. I am using it to implement Algolia search.

Please help I am really new at this.